# Text submitted from an Android app doesn't encode correctly

Tags: android, encoding

I have an Android app and it allows users to post text.  I'm noticing that certain text like 'ó' and other text with the accent above it ends up getting changed to a '?'.

I haven't hand any luck searching Google about this.  My android app posts to an API.  I've tested the API using other clients such as an iPhone app, a C# app and a web app and none of the other clients have issues with the special characters.

Is there some setting when doing an http post or before the post that I need to change in Android?

Comment: I think you should use custom fonts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font. I am not sure if this what your looking for. Have a look at the link.

Comment: I don't think it's the fonts that are the problem.  My Android app can display characters like 'ó' correctly, but if I post that character to my API it changes to a '?'.  I think it has something to do with Android encoding and httppost, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

For me the answer was found here:

[Setting encoding for a Multipart Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791508/setting-encoding-for-a-multipart-entity)

I was using a multipart entity when doing an httppost so all that was needed was to set the encoding to UTF-8 and it seems to work out ok.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question which helped me solve my problem :)

The following links also proved useful:

[Android : upload Image and JSON using MultiPartEntityBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239923/android-upload-image-and-json-using-multipartentitybuilder)

[MultipartEntityBuilder and Charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292169/multipartentitybuilder-and-charset)

Steps that I followed:

1. Downloaded latest jar
   httpcore-4.3.jar
   httpmime-4.3.3.jar (This contains the MultipartEntityBuilder class)
2. With the latest version of hhtpmime jar  you can use the entity.addTextBody(). This helps in posting the text consisting special characters.
3. Refer these jars in you project.