# Android : upload Image and JSON using MultiPartEntityBuilder

Tags: android, json, http-post, multipartentity

I try to upload data to server, my data containing multiple images and large `JSON`, before it, I Try to send with convert image to string using `base64` and send my another data and image that I've convert before with `JSON`, but I face Problem `OutOfMemory` here, so I read one of solutions that said I must to try using `MultipartEntityBuilder`.
I still confusing and not understand how to do it with `MultiPartEntityBuilder`, Is there anyone can help me the way to do it with `MultiPartEntityBuilder`? this is my code :

```
    try{
    //membuat HttpClient
    //membuat HttpPost
    HttpPost httpPost= new HttpPost(url);
    SONObject jsonObjectDP= new JSONObject();
    System.out.println("file audio "+me.getModelDokumenPendukung().getAudio());
    jsonObjectDP.put("audio_dp",MethodEncode.EncodeAudio(me.getModelDokumenPendukung().getAudio()));
    jsonObjectDP.put("judul_audio",me.getModelDokumenPendukung().getJudul_audio());
    jsonObjectDP.put("ket_audio",me.getModelDokumenPendukung().getKet_audio());
    JSONArray ArrayFoto= new JSONArray();

    //This loop For my multiple File  Images
    List<ModelFoto>ListFoto=me.getModelDokumenPendukung().getListFoto();
    for (int i=0; i<ListFoto.size();i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("foto", ListFoto.get(i).getFile_foto());
        jsonObject.put("judul_foto", ListFoto.get(i).getJudul_foto());
        jsonObject.put("ket_foto", ListFoto.get(i).getKet_foto());
        ArrayFoto.put(jsonObject);

    }

    JSONObject JSONESPAJ=null;
     JSONESPAJ = new JSONObject();
     JSONObject JSONFINAL = new JSONObject();
            JSONESPAJ.put("NO_PROPOSAL",me.getModelID().getProposal());
            JSONESPAJ.put("GADGET_SPAJ_KEY",me.getModelID().getIDSPAJ());
            JSONESPAJ.put("NO_VA",me.getModelID().getVa_number());
            JSONESPAJ.put("Dokumen_Pendukung",jsonObjectDP);

            JSONFINAL.put("ESPAJ", JSONESPAJ);
            JSONFINAL.put("CLIENT", "ANDROID");
            JSONFINAL.put("APP", "ESPAJ");

            MultipartEntityBuilder multiPartEntityBuilder= MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    multiPartEntityBuilder.addPart("ESPAJ",JSONFINAL.toString());

    httpPost.setEntity(multiPartEntityBuilder.build());

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);


    inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        if(inputStream != null)
        result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
    else
        result = "Did not work!";
}catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
      Log.e("MEMORY EXCEPTION: ", e.toString());
} catch(ConnectTimeoutException e){
    Log.e("Timeout Exception: ", e.toString());
} catch(SocketTimeoutException ste){    
    Log.e("Timeout Exception: ", ste.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
//    Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
//      hasil=line;
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

is there anyone can help me to teach and tell me how to send JSON and Image using MultiPartEntityBuilder?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To send binary data you need to use `addBinaryBody` method of `MultipartEntityBuilder`. Sample of attaching:

```
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
//Image attaching
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
File file;
multipartEntity.addBinaryBody("someName", file, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), file.getName());
//Json string attaching
String json;
multipartEntity.addPart("someName", new StringBody(json, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```

Then make request as usual:

```
HttpPut put = new HttpPut("url");
put.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Comment: so for JSON how to send it?

Comment: @NenMa json is just a string. So send it as usual plain text. I've updated answer.

Comment: so you mean I must to convert my JSON as String first, right?

Comment: anb btw why I can't import `org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;` T.T ?

Comment: @NenMa yes, you need to convert to String your json. `ContentType` is a part of `httpcore-4.3.2.jar`. You can download it here: https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

Comment: +1 for your help, I can't accept your answer because I still waiting for another answer and btw I make request with `HttpPost` not `httpPut`, is it okay?

Comment: @NenMa Yeah, it's ok. Actually it depends on your server. If it accepts files on `POST` request then send it using `POST` method.

Answer (score 1):

There is my solution, for sending images and text fields (with apache http libraries) with POST request. Json could be added in the same way, as my fields group and owner.

```
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(StaticData.AMBAJE_SERVER_URL + StaticData.AMBAJE_ADD_AMBAJ_TO_GROUP);

            String boundary = "-------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();

            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);

            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(imageBytes, "pic.png");
            StringBody sbOwner = new StringBody(StaticData.loggedUserId, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            StringBody sbGroup = new StringBody("group", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

            HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                    .setBoundary(boundary)
                    .addPart("group", sbGroup)
                    .addPart("owner", sbOwner)
                    .addPart("image", bab)
                    .build();

            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                ...then reading response
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Log.d(LOG_SERVICE_TAG, "Sending Multipart Image with Json data"+");      
    InputStream imageStream;
    JSONObject objResult;
    boolean bSucess = true;
            // Base 64 image string was stored with image object , 
    String imageBase64 = image.getImageString();
    // This base64 to byte , One can directly read bytes from file from Disk
    String imageDataBytes = imageBase64.substring( imageBase64.indexOf(",")+1);
    HttpClient client = null;
    HttpPost post = null;
    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    String result;
    imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(imageDataBytes.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));   
    try{
        //Forming Json Object 
        JSONObject jsonImageMetdata = new JSONObject();     
        JSONObject objMultipart = new JSONObject();     
        try {
            objMultipart.put("param1", "param 1 value");
            objMultipart.put("param2",  "param 2 value"  );
            objMultipart.put("param3","param 3 value" );
            objMultipart.put("param4", "param 4 value");                
            jsonImageMetdata.put("MultipartImageMetadata", objMultipart);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // converting json data to string
        String strImageMetadata = jsonImageMetdata.toString();
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        post = new HttpPost("https://abcd");
        MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = null;
        try{
            entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        }
        catch(Exception a){
            Log.d("name",a.getMessage());
            throw a;                
        }
        entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);    

        // adding text
        entityBuilder.addTextBody("dummyParameter","Dummy text",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);             

        // adding Image
        if(imageStream != null){                
            entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", imageStream,ContentType.create("image/jpeg"),"imagename.jpg");
        }         

        // sending formed json data in form of text
        entityBuilder.addTextBody("descriptions", strImageMetadata, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON) ;
        HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
        post.setEntity(entity);         
        response = client.execute(post);
        httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

> Download httpcore-4.3.2.jar , httpmime-4.3.3.jar from Apache and add them in lib folder of Android project for using MultipartEntityBuilder