# MultipartEntityBuilder and Charset

Tags: java, character-encoding

I upgraded my httpmime package, and now my strings are not sent or received as UTF-8

```
MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
Charset chars = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
entity.setCharset(chars);
entity.addTextBody("some_text", some_text);

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url); 
httppost.setEntity(entity.build());
...and so on..
```

what am I missing?
I used to build a StringBody and set the charset in the stringbody, but that is deprecated now, and it just doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Solved it :) it turns out that ContentType is now important, and I was sending text that was plain, and also some text that was JSON,

for the plain text, you can use:

```
entity.addTextBody("plain_text",plain_text,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
```

and for JSON:

```
entity.addTextBody("json_text",json_text,ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

that way the charset also works on JSON strings (weird, but now OK)

Comment: As far as the document page http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/StringBody.html#StringBody(java.lang.String, org.apache.http.entity.ContentType) says, StringBody(String text, ContentType contentType, Charset charset) is not deprecated in 4.3.x

Answer (score 22):

```
entity.addTextBody("plain_text", plain_text);
```

will use the default ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN which look like this...

```
public static final ContentType TEXT_PLAIN = ContentType.create("text/plain", Consts.ISO_8859_1);
```

while ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON is using UTF-8 as below

```
public static final ContentType APPLICATION_JSON = ContentType.create("application/json", Consts.UTF_8);
```

So what i did was create our own ContentType like this..

```
entity.addTextBody("plain_text", plain_text, ContentType.create("text/plain", MIME.UTF8_CHARSET));
```

Comment: Above Solution didn't worked for me, this did (http*-4.3.6.jar). +1

Comment: `ContentType.create("text/plain", MIME.UTF8_CHARSET)` worked for me. You are my hero.

Answer (score 10):

For those who say the accepted solution did not work for them (it didn't for me either), I solved it a different way, using:

```
builder.addTextBody(key, שלום, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN.withCharset("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this for

> Utf-8:

```
entity.addTextBody("your text", stringBuffer.toString(), ContentType.create("text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I setup the contentType first like this

```
ContentType contentType = ContentType.create(
                        HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

and when adding pairs , specify the content type like this

```
entityBuilder.addTextBody("title",pic.getTitle(),contentType);
```

as answered here [MultipartEntityBuilder and setCharset for UTF-8 sends empty content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230242/multipartentitybuilder-and-setcharset-for-utf-8-sends-empty-content/25353597#25353597)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the JSON string to BinaryUTF8 also is another way that works fine:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder meb = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
meb.setCharset(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byte[] bytes = StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(some_text);
meb.addBinaryBody("JSON", bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way, using: `ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN.withCharset("UTF-8")`.

```
MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entityBuilder.addTextBody("operation", "postdita");
entityBuilder.addTextBody("path", .getPath(),ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN.withCharset("UTF-8"));
entityBuilder.addTextBody("createrev", "false");
entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("editorData", file);
entityBuilder.addTextBody("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```