# UTF-8 characters in HTTP POST query form parameters

Tags: java, http, utf-8, apache-httpclient-4.x, formidable

I am trying to transfer form data from an Android application to a NodeJs server.
My client code is the following (the strings that can contain UTF-8 characters are the values of `params`):

```
final HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

final MultipartEntityBuilder mpb = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))  // tried with or without this line
.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE); // tried with or without this line

for (final Entry<String, String> e : params.entrySet()) {
  mpb.addTextBody(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
}
post.setEntity(mpb.build());
final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

And my server code is the following:

```
app.post('/accesspoint', function(req, res) {
  var body = req.body;
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.encoding = 'utf-8';

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    console.log(fields);
    ...
```

When my input java `params` has a value containing an UTF-8 character, the log I get server side prints the corresponding value without this character, so it is kind of swallowed at some point. For instance if my input string is `"ê"`, then my server log will print a `""` value.

I use a multipart form as I read that it was the best way to send data that can contain non-ASCII characters. Formidable is also apparently the best node package to handle form that can contain UTF-8 characters.

My client side uses Apache HttpClient 4.3.3.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the headers of the HTTP connection? Is an appropriate header sent to tell the server that the client is sending UTF-8? I'm not familiar with the API, so I don't know if that `setCharset` call causes an appropriate header to be sent.

Comment: How do you know the problem is with the client ? Have you tried intercepting the request with a proxy like Charles and checking if the UTF-8 characters are transmitted correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I tested with a simple query and the key value `("foo","[ê]")` looked at the headers and I saw that my query was still using ISO-8859-1

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
[]
```

in contradiction to my builder parameter.
I found the solution via https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020435/592392 and changed my code to:

```
for (final Entry<String, String> e : params.entrySet()) {
      mpb.addTextBody(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), ContentType.create("text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    }
```

And now the server gets the UTF8 chars :)

Anyway, the form builder is quite misleading in my opinion.